# Getting a weird persistance issue with ember data fragments and localstorage

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Apologies if this isn't quite the right place (as opposed to either libraries own github issue page, but as I've not been able to determine exactly which library is not quite working correctly hard to log it specifically).

I'm using ember data fragments on my model (an array), and localstorage to save down my model. When calling rollback upon the saved model, it seems to reset the fragments back to their original state (i.e. no values), but it still maintains the fragment itself on the array, rather than dropping the item out of the array.

I've got a [fiddle setup](http://jsfiddle.net/e22hfsec/1/), click 'add' to add a model, click to view it's details, then click 'add' in there, followed by 'cancel'. You can see that the type + desc values drop out, but the element is still there.

If I switch out to using the Fixture adapter then it all works as expected, just not sure where to start even attempting to debug, I've stepped through many lines of _super calls, and what not trying to figure it out, but just get lost.

**Note**

This is a pseudo version of my actual app, and curiously enough when you navigate to the home page and then back to the details page, it seems to resolve the type/desc correctly, which it is not doing on my actual app, it still maintains the default values. However refreshing the page makes it work perfectly from then onwards.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.7.0/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments/master/dist/ember-data.model-fragments.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter/master/localstorage_adapter.js"></script>
<script>
    window.App = Ember.Application.create();    

    App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend();

    App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.LSSerializer.extend();

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
        namespace: 'cars'
    });

    App.Car = DS.Model.extend({
      make: DS.attr(),
      model: DS.attr(),
      features: DS.hasManyFragments('feature')
    });

    App.Feature = DS.ModelFragment.extend({
      type: DS.attr(),
      description: DS.attr()
    });

    App.Router.map(function () {
        this.route('index', { path: '/' });
        this.route('car', { path: '/car/:car_id'});
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return this.store.find('car');
      },

      actions : {
        add: function(model) {
            var car = this.store.createRecord('car', {
                make: 'Dodge',
                model: 'Viper',
                features: []
            });
            car.save();
        }
      }
    });

    App.CarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        actions: {
            add: function(model) {
                model.get('features').createFragment({
                    type: 'Something',
                    description: 'Some desc'
                });
                model.save(); //*/
            },
            cancel: function(model) {
              model.rollback();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
        {{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}
        <ol>{{#each}}
            <li>{{#link-to 'car' this}}{{name}} {{model}}{{/link-to}}</li>
        {{else}}
            <button {{action 'add' model}}>Add</button>
        {{/each}}</ol>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="car">
  {{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}
  <dl>
    <dt>Make</dt>
    <dd>{{make}}
    <dt>Model</dt>
    <dd>{{model.model}}</dd>{{#each features}}
    <dt>{{_view.contentIndex}}. {{type}}</dt>
    <dd>{{description}}</dd>
    {{/each}}
  </dl>
  <button {{action 'add' model}}>Add</button>
  <button {{action 'cancel' model}}>Cancel</button>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with data fragments but fragment is a model itself so the element/fragment is still there because you have created a record for it.
This record is stored in the ember store until you do something with it.
Rollback, via emberjs.com,does this - "If the model isDirty this function will discard any unsaved changes".
The model in this case seems to be the fragment. Rollback gets rid of the changes, which is what it is doing in your case, removing the type and desc values, but the record itself is still in the store.
If you want to get rid of the fragment altogether you would have to delete it. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/

Comment: Refreshing the page isn't clearing the store though, it restores the original value of the fragments (or it is at least for me). When the `add` on the `CarRoute` is fired it's calling `model.save()` which is saving the fragments, and making them non-dirty

Comment: yeah sorry my bad, point should still be the same though, `rollback()` wont get rid of the fragment because its a record, and because the rollback looks like its being called on the fragment and not the car. Your fiddle wont work for me so I cant test it. If you add `Ember.Logger.log(model);` in the `cancel function` before `model.rollback()` and check the console it should give you which model the `rollback()` is being called on. To get rid of the fragment you'll have to delete it.